# handle click event on item in listbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some line chart which gets data from controller.Also I have Methods ListBox with  with some SelectListItem items. When I click on any of these items in Listbox I get graphId and then it pass to controller to "Coordinates" method and this method creates dataCoord list with (x,y) coordinates. So question is how do I modify my script to pass this dataCoord list to my line chart by clicking on any item in Method ListBox

here is Coordinates method:

```
 public JsonResult Coordinates(int graphId)
    {   
        List<DataPoint> dataCoords = new List<DataPoint> { };

        string exp = "GRAPHIC_ID = " + graphId;

        DataRow[] foundrows;

        foundrows = oraVars.Ds.Tables["COORDS"].Select(exp);

        for (int i = 0; i < foundrows.Length; i++)
        {

            double x = Convert.ToDouble(foundrows[i].ItemArray[1]);

            double y = Convert.ToDouble(foundrows[i].ItemArray[2]);

            dataCoords.Add(new DataPoint(x, y));
        }

        return Json(dataCoords, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

here is  script in view:

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#MethodsListBoxValues").change(function () {
                    $.ajax({
    type:   'POST',
    url:    '@Url.Action("coordinates")',
    dataType:  'json',
                        data: { graphId: $("#GraphicListBoxValues").val() },                  

                    "how to modify script?"
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed.' + ex);
                    }
                });
                return false;
                })
            });
```

here is line chart script:

```
            window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            theme: "light2",
            animationEnabled: true,
            title: {
                text: "Simple Column Chart in ASP.NET MVC"
            },
            subtitles: [
                { text: "Try Resizing the Browser" }
            ],
            data: [
            {
                type: "line", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                dataPoints:@Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints),

            }
            ]
        });
        chart.render();
    };
```

Comment: Try adding `success: function (result) { console.log(result) }` to see the JSON data. Are you want to reinitialize the CanvasJS chart with provided data points from JSON response?

Comment: it didnt work out :( Yeah, every time when I click on item in list box I want to CanvasJs chart to be updated accroding value (graphId) I get